# How to transform payload data after it comes in using Pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a payload that comes in which has two parameters. One of the parameters is a long string which contains more parameters. Something like this `param1%param2%param3`. I am using FastAPI and Pydantic BaseModel to get that data and validate it, however since I am using it in other places I also want to transform it and store it in an object so I can access it later without having to transform it when I need to. Something like `PayloadObject.param1`.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Payload(BaseModel):
    string_params: str #param1%param2%param3
    second_param: dict

    @validator(string_params)
    def string_params_validator(cls, strings_params):
        #validation stuff
    @validator(second_param)
    def second_param(cls, second_param):
        #validation stuff

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/my_route")
async def post_my_route(payload: Payload):
    # want to have transformed payload around here
    func(payload)
```

What would be the best way to go about that using pydantic?

I am just thinking of making a class that transforms this information on `__init__` without using BaseModel. So after I get that data from the request and validate it I run it through this class and get a format that I am happy with.

```
class NewPayload:

    def __init__(self, payload: Payload):
        # do transformations so i end up with
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.param3 = param3
        self.second_param = second_param
```

Comment: No it's not. The data has to come in as a JSON payload.

Answer (score 0):

If this payload structure is specific to this route it's a good idea to transform it directly in your route def.

The structure you gave for NewPayload will not work if the number of param isn't always the same.

**example 1:**

```py
from typing import List

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Payload(BaseModel):
    string_params: str #param1%param2%param3
    second_param: dict

    @validator(string_params)
    def string_params_validator(cls, strings_params):
        #validation stuff

    @validator(second_param)
    def second_param(cls, second_param):
        #validation stuff

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/my_route")
async def post_my_route(payload: Payload):
    params: List[str] = payload.string_params.split("%")
    # params = ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
    # Do something with params
    func(payload)
```

**Another idea**:

not the best since you accept the data in list format also, you can add a validator to stop this behavior but it will modify the doc

```py
from typing import List

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Payload(BaseModel):
    string_params: Union[str, List[str]] #param1%param2%param3
    second_param: dict

    @validator(string_params)
    def string_params_validator(cls, strings_params):
        string_params = strings_params.split("%")
        return string_params
    
    @validator(string_params)
    def params_to_list(cls, strings_params):
        #validation stuff

    @validator(second_param)
    def second_param(cls, second_param):
        #validation stuff

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/my_route")
async def post_my_route(payload: Payload):
    func(payload)
```

You can use a second pydantic model with the second solution to only accept str in input and cast your first model into the other.

```
from typing import List

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Payload(BaseModel):
    string_params: str #param1%param2%param3
    second_param: dict

    @validator(string_params)
    def params_to_list(cls, strings_params):
        #validation stuff

    @validator(second_param)
    def second_param(cls, second_param):
        #validation stuff

class Payload1(BaseModel):
    string_params: Union[str, List[str]]
    second_param: dict

    @validator(string_params)
    def string_params_validator(cls, strings_params):
        string_params = strings_params.split("%")
        return string_params

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/my_route")
async def post_my_route(payload: Payload):
    params: Payload1 = Payload1(**Payload.dict())
    func(payload)
```

In the end the cleaner solution would be to make string_params a list of str and not a simple str since you will always need to convert it to list

Comment: Yes I pretty much arrived at the same conclusion. I just decided to use a function dependancy which transforms the data as I need and does some basic checks to ensure something is there then passes it to another pydantic base model that has more in-depth validation and gives me access the parameters as I need them.

Pretty much this.https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/